# How to get the record by comparing the date field

Tags: solr, solrj

In my Solr, there are tow records:

```
ID  name document_date
--  ---- -------------
1   A     20/12/2013
2   A     24/12/2013
```

How can I use the Solr query to retrieve only the record (ID=2) with the latest document date (document_date='24/12/2013')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now your question makes sense to me.

You need to use the FieldCollapsing feature in SOLR.

You can get the feature in below link:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping

Using above feature you can 1 or N documnets to user from a particular group and you can also view all other documents by firing a particular query.

You will also have to apply sortby document_date to get the lates document on the top.

Then you will get the latest document at the top.

Regards,

Jayesh Bhoyar

http://technical-fundas.blogspot.in/2014/06/zookeeper-cluster-setup.html

Comment: But I get plenty of documents and I need to group them by name field